# Comparing versions in Ruby with develop-SNAPSHOT

Tags: ruby

I am looking to compare package versions in ruby. Some of my package names are develop-SNAPSHOT.

When using something like

```
Gem::Version.new('develop-SNAPSHOT-1529333073') > Gem::Version.new('develop-SNAPSHOT')
```

I get the response

```
ArgumentError: Malformed version number string develop-SNAPSHOT-1529333073
```

In python I would use packaging.version.parse() to compare similar strings to this and it would work fine with that, is there anything equivalent in Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

According to [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Version.html):

> A version string should normally be a series of numbers separated by periods. Each part (digits separated by periods) is considered its own number, and these are used for sorting. So for instance, 3.10 sorts higher than 3.2 because ten is greater than two.

So your version strings (`'develop-SNAPSHOT-1529333073'` and `'develop-SNAPSHOT'`) are both in wrong format.

You should change format of your version string, e.g. to just `'1529333073'` without prefix and everything will be OK.

If you want to have prefix in your version strings, you need remove it before using `Gem::Version.new()`.
For example, the code below will work as you expected:

```
Gem::Version.new('develop-SNAPSHOT-1529333073'.sub(/develop-SNAPSHOT-?/, '')) > 
   Gem::Version.new('develop-SNAPSHOT'.sub(/develop-SNAPSHOT-?/, ''))

=> true
```